# In regexp, what is this ---> "?!"

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to invert a regular expression, i want to match all strings which doesnt have  a special email username in them. like:

```
my email is myriam@example.com and I love programming
my email is myriam@yahoo.com and I love programming
my email is myriam@google.com and I love programming
my email is myriam@gmail.com and I love programming
```

all shouldn't be matched.

if i want to match them i use `/myriam@.*[\.].*/`. a friend told me that if i want to invert it, i must use `?!`, but i can't find out how?

Comment: see this :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804732/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-regex

Comment: You don't need to invert the regex, you just need to invert the matching function. E.g. `if (!str.match(/.../))`...

Comment: this is not good. i want to use regex itself

Comment: A regex itself doesn't strictly have a concept of "inversion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?!)` is **negative lookahead**

So your regex would be

```
^(?!.*myriam@example\.com).*$
```

---

`Regex` is not required for this problem you can instead use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method to check if the string contains that particular email!

Comment: I don't know why you would suggest regex solution. Although it is correct, it is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It's negative lookahead. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)