# Question mark with equal to sign in regex

Tags: regex

Hey Experts i am new to regex.I am really confused by studying this regex.I have found something which is very difficult to understand for me.The thing is the use of question mark and equal to symbol in regex.An eg :

```
"(?<=\d)(\s)(?=[\d-])"
```

I just need to know the use of `?=` in this regex  code..I have searched google many times in this case but i didnt find any solution there.So i came here It will be a great help for me if you answer this one correctly for me  ..:) ..

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: What system or language is this regex used in?

Comment: This is a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). I find [this cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/) especially helpful for understanding all of the special regex characters

Comment: "Lookahead assertions" are called "positive lookaheads", too - just if you stumble upon this

Comment: +1 for mentioning "question mark" and "equals" in your text. This is what I call search engine friendly :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At least in JavaScript, the `?=` matches a suffix but excludes it from capture. `?=` excludes the expression from the entire match. For more information, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804732/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-regex) question and it's corresponding answers.

Comment: This can be used nicely for password validation: `^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[*.!@$%^&(){}[]:;<>,.?/~_+-=|\]).{8,32}$` https://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/password-regular-expression/

Comment: Great answers!  @halllo, is there any reason you included the period in the list twice (it is the 2nd and 20th in the list)?

Comment: Also @halllo, in python3 the square brackets don't work in this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.match(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@$%^&(){}[]]).{8,}$', 'Testing13!'))
None
>>> print(re.match(r'^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@$%^&(){}]).{8,}$', 'Testing13!'))
<re.Match object; span=(0, 10), match='Testing13!'>
```

Answer (score 25):

This is a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

The part before is only matched if followed by `[\d-]`

You should notice the start of the expression is, symmetrically, a lookbehind.

Both groups are not capturing. To sum it up, this regular expression matches a space following a digit and followed either by a digit or a minus sign. For example it matches the space in `"3 4"`.

Be careful that many languages/engines don't support lookbehind, for performance and predictability reason (see [this interesting article](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) for example).

Comment: `"(?<=\d)(\s)(?=[\d-])"`, digit is first and then space and digit?